# Is there a way to pass self by default?

Tags: swift

I'm creating a `log` method which prints the info (similar to [MLog](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/MLog/blob/master/MLog.h))

```
#define MDLog(format, ...) NSLog(@"<%p> %s [#%d]| "format@"\n\n", self, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

I'm able to get the file name, method name and the line number but I want to print the address of the calling object as well for that I need `self`. **But** I don't want to pass self every time I call the `log` method. So is there a way to pass `self` by default?

e.g.

```
func log(message: String, object: NSObject = __SELF_HERE__ , functionName: String = __FUNCTION__, fileName: String = __FILE__, lineNumber: Int = __LINE__) {
  print("\(message)")
  print("\(functionName)")
  print("\(fileName)")
  print("\(lineNumber)")
  print("\(myObj)")
}
```

**P.S.** Solutions I have in mind if nothing works.

1. Pass `self` as parameter in the `log` method. (will prefer this one)
2. Create extension for `NSObject/UIViewController` which have `log` method

Comment: When considering your solution #2, bear in mind that not all Swift objects are `NSObject`s.

Comment: @MattGibson Yes you're right considering it moving in 'UIViewController` as we need most of the logs there. But I would prefer method #1 instead :)